# Case function based on more than 1 column

Tags: sql-server

Ok, just a quick question in regard to using the CASE function.  Not sure if I'm able to use it the way I am as seen in the example below but I want to use based on the district and bankcode.  Can someone please assist with the syntax on doing so.

Table: **BankInfo**:

```
 BankCode      PayeeName        District
   101          John Doe           333
   101          Doe John           233
   100          Jane Doe           333
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    PayeeName, BankCode
   ,CASE dbo.BankInfo.district
         WHEN 333 and BankCode = 101 THEN '79999'
    END as BankTransit
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using two columns, you need to change it to be:

```
SELECT 
    PayeeName, BankCode,
    CASE 
       WHEN dbo.BankInfo.district = 333 AND BankCode = 101 
       THEN '79999'
    END as BankTransit
```

Comment: Tried this but get an error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'"

Answer (score 0):

A generic Northwind example:

```
Select
CustomerID , PostalCode ,
[MyMatch] = 
CASE
    When CustomerID = 'ALFKI' and PostalCode = '12209' then 1
    else 0
END

 from [dbo].[Customers]

Order by 3 DESC ,1,2
```

and translated........
I have an alias "MyDerived1Value".  And an "else" statement.

```
Select
PayeeName, BankCode , 
[MyDerivedValue] = 
CASE
    When District = '333' and BankCode = '101' then '79999'
    else null
END

 from [dbo].BankInfo

Order by 3 DESC ,1,2
```

if District and/or BankCode is an int, then remove the single quotes.